# main memory addresses, how to define pages and allocate them

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, operating-system

I am developing a small operating system (32-bit) using C, and I'm struggling to understand the concepts of the main memory:

Assume that:

- I have 32MB memory space, 32-bit machine, then I have a space up to 4GB in my memory, and addresses can range from 0 to 0xffffffff.
- I will divide my memory into fixed size partitions (pages), then each page can hold up to 2^32 instructions and I can have up to 2^32 pages (is this correct?)
- I would maintain the space in my memory using memory table that makes each page as free or allocated.

What I don't understand is how to use the addresses? what does each address mean? Is it a byte, a word or what?

And if I divide my memory into 4KB pages, how can I reference these pages? and how do I link each page with its corresponding process? and if a process needs more than one page, how can divide it into multiple pages?

Any reference or help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: 4 GB would be from ' to 0xffffffff, not 0x7fffffff.

Comment: Why can't addresses range up to 0xFFFFFFFF?

Comment: BTW the size of a page that can hold up 2^32 instructions would be 4GB (assuming each instruction takes one byte). Your question is pretty unclear. Please elaborate.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  that was a typo .. thanks for point this out

Comment: @MichaelWalz .. I have read this here (http://www.cs.ucv.ro/English/staff/dmancas/CA/course_07.pdf , pages 8-9) that's why I'm asking if it is correct or not .. apparently it is not.

Comment: Do you intend to use virtual memory concepts?

Comment: @4386427 yes but not for now .. now I just want to preserve some memory directly

Comment: Your question contains some fundamental misunderstandings that you need to clear up before attempting to write an OS. Example: 2^32 is 4G. An instruction is at least 1 byte but typically 4 bytes or more. That depends on the Instruction Set of the CPU used. To hold 2^32 instructions in a single page, you'll probably need near 16G byte of memory. That is impossible with a 32 bit CPU. Further, having 2^32 pages on a 32 bit CPU makes no sense at all. I think you have a basic misunderstanding of what a page is, how large it is, why it is used.... (cont)

Comment: .... (cont)  Since you say that you want virtual memory in the end, I'll suggest that you starting studying the MMU of the CPU you are using.